# React-Bootstrap Modal mobile size has a additional white space

Tags: bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap4-modal

[image]

I'm using react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5"

I just cannot get rid of the extra white space created by the dialog / modal for my modal, on mobile view.

i've read a few threads refering to it as bootstrap 3. I did tried to cahnge the bootstrap.css file but it didnt seem to work for me.

can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

So, I found out the issue.

the issue was with the  Component that i was using surprisingly it is messing up with the margins of -15px for left and right. ALTHOUGH i added them into the container correctly.

The trick that i did was to overwrite the .row css class in that page to remove the -15px for both left and right.